# How to upgrade the older demo to latest version of three.js?

Tags: three.js

I got a webgl demo running with old version of Three.js (r52).
I want to adapt the code to new version of Three.js (r1xx).
But I got some black screen after I switched to the new version of Three.js library and upgrade some api.(e.g. Moving the attributes values to BufferGeometry)
This is the shader code passed to ShaderMaterial:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
  attribute float size;
  attribute vec3 customColor;
  attribute float time;
  uniform float globalTime;

  varying vec3 vColor;
  varying float fAlpha;

  void main() {

    vColor = customColor;

    vec3 pos = position; 

    float animTime = min(1.4, max(1.0, globalTime - time));

    vec3 animated = vec3( pos.x * animTime, pos.y * animTime, pos.z * animTime );

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( animated, 1.0 );

    fAlpha = 1.0 - (globalTime*0.5);

    gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

  }
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

  uniform vec3 color;
  uniform sampler2D texture;

  varying vec3 vColor;
  varying float fAlpha;

  void main() {

    // fog
    float depth = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;
    float near = 30.0;
    float far = 290.0;
    float fog = 0.0 + smoothstep( near, far, depth );

    vec4 outColor = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
    if ( outColor.a < 0.25 ) discard; // alpha be gone

    gl_FragColor = vec4( color * vColor, fAlpha );
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * outColor;
    gl_FragColor = mix( gl_FragColor, vec4( vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0), gl_FragColor.w ), fog );

  }

</script>
```

It seems that the ShaderMaterial is not working well.

Does anyone know if I missed something?

Older one:

https://loooog.github.io/globe/legacy

The failed new one:

https://loooog.github.io/globe/

### The code can be seen from the chrome dev console.

Update: the shader material issue has been solved. The line material is still not working

Comment: Attributes now are part of a buffer geometry, not of a material.

Comment: S.O. is not a forum. Just putting links to code offsite is off topic.

Comment: @prisoner849 Yes. I have modified that part to adapt the new api. But I got black screen with the shader material. If I replace the shader material with MeshBasicMaterial, the mesh is showing.

Answer (score 0):

//var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial, THREE.LineSegments);

var line = new THREE.LineSegments(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);